# How can I write a program in python that approximates the value of pi by summing the terms of the Leibniz series?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below are the guidelines for the problem. My class is using Python 3.5. Thank you so much!

Write a program that approximates the value of pi by summing the terms of the Gregory Leibniz
series:

```
-4/1 – 4/3 + 4/5 – 4/7 + 4/9 – 4/11 + 4/13 …
```

-The program must prompt the user for the number of terms to sum, then display the iteration number, approximation of pi, and the absolute value of the difference between pi from the `math` library and your approximation each time a new term is included in the series.

This is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    n = int(input("Please enter a value for N:"))
    for i in range(1,n,7):
        total = ((1.0/(i+i+1))-(1.0)/(i+i+2))+(1.0)/(i+i+4)

    value = 4*(1-total)
    print(value)

main()
```

Comment: How's it working...or not?

Comment: @zondo If I enter 8, it gives me 3.0, not pi. Thanks.

Comment: Your program doesnt sum terms into total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oups!
You made great efforts to make as many mistakes in so few lines of code :-)

As every **second** term in Leibniz series is negative, you should process numbers stepping by 2:

```
def main():
    n = int(input("Please enter a value for N:"))
    total = 0
    for i in range(0,n,2):
        total += ((1.0/(i+i+1))-(1.0)/(i+i+3))

    value = 4*total
    print(value)
```

But Leibniz series has a very slow convergence. For `n=10000` you still only get `3.14149265359` ...

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things wrong with your code:

1. You're incrementing `i` by `7` in `range(1, n, 7)`.
2. Every second term in the Leibniz series is negative, yours is not.
3. You are not adding the terms to `total`, you are only storing the last value into `total`.

Editing your code, this will give you what you want:

```
def main():
    n = int(input("Please enter a value for N:"))
    total=0
    for i in range(1,n):
        total += (-1)**(i+1)*((1.0/(i+i+1)))

    value = 4*(1-total)
    print(value)

main()
```

Now giving a value of `1000` for `N`, you would get `3.1405926538397924`.